# Storing plugins from target platform in local directory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse likes to reload my current target definition and so resolving all plugins listed in this target definition.
I use a lot of plugins which are available from software sites what increases the time for resolving by downloading these plugins.
Is it possible storing these plugins in a local folder only if I add locations to the target definition? Or is it possible as another solution denying the reload ater all plugins are resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple options for this.

Option 1 - the proper solution

You can use the [p2 mirror application](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_mirror.html?cp=2_0_20_3_0) to mirror the source repositories to corresponding local repositories and setup your target from those local repos.
So repo resolvement will happen instantly and if you like to have a offline pde build the required repos are also already there.

Option 2 - quick hack

Copy the content of the PDE target caching
`<wrkspc>/.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool` folder to an other local destination and configure this as target.

Comment: Thank you. I took Option 1 and created an ant task. It raises Exceptions concerning the platformFilter option but nevertheless it's what I was looking for.

Comment: Do not filter during mirroring. Use the raw switch. Filter only in the target file.